# Вывод переменной, как сообщение telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
if message.text == 'Далее':
    i += 1
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Страница:', i)
```

Как отправить пользователю значение переменной i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, комментарии не нужны, только есть один совет, пользуйтесь гуглом, а так вот ответ:

`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Страница: {i}')`