# Вывод переменной через bot.send.massage

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Нужно вывести значение переменной pricesale + текст

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['price'])
   def start_message(message):
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Цена - ',pricesale)
```

Однако выводит при этом только текст или только значение переменной если убрать текст
Нашел вот такой ответ [Вывод переменной, как сообщение telebot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1000449/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-telebot) Но т.к на сервере на котором я хочу развернуть скрипт установлен 3.5.2, а он не поддерживает f строки то нужно переписать скрипт без них. Какие есть варианты

Comment: как вариант можно изучить питон и прочитать про конкатенацию

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать форматирование в стиле `C`:

```py
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Цена - %s' % pricesale)
```

Comment: Или использовать format: `'Цена - {}'.format(pricesale)`

Answer (score 2):

А если попробовать

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Цена - " + str(pricesale))
```